# Error: "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" when using GPU tensorflow (spyder)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, spyder

I am getting an error with the kernel when activating my GPU for tensorflow. I have installed Tensorflow 2.7 , CUDA 11.5 and CUDNN 8.3.2 . I have tried in an environment python 3.9 and 3.8.12. My GPU is well activated but for some reason the kernel stops working when starting the epoch calculation. I have checked all posible solutions in the web and nothing works for me.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5sA7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I had similar problems because of CUDNN  8.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

in case if you are using anaconda:
please check the cudnn and cuda version installed using the following commands

```
conda list cudatoolkit

conda list cudnn
```

If you haven't installed any of them:
do so:

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
conda install -c anaconda cudnn
```

Comment: As I see no one accepted this I wanted to comment that this worked for me. Had to manually set up the $PATH for the NVIDIA and cuDNN bin directories before this.